# Can't make hibernate stop showing SQL using Spring JPA Vendor Adapter

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa

Hibernate is continuing to spew SQL traces to stdout, and I can't figure out how to change a Hibernate configuration property when it's hidden behind a JPA adapter.  This is the Spring bean for the entityManagerFactory:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ssapDataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" >
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Even with the showSql property set to false, Hibernate keeps printing SQL.

I've tried making a hibernate.properties file in my classpath with "hibernate.show_sql=false", but it didn't pick that up either.

Comment: I also tried setting a system property: hibernate.show_sql=false. Still no joy.  It insists on spewing SQL statements.

Comment: How about specifying <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/> ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Hibernate doesn't do this by default, so I suspect that somewhere else in your environment you have something that has turned showSql on, and this is taking precedence over your attempts to turn it off.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try setting it in persistance.xml

```
<persistence>
  <persistence-unit name="PU">
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: The turns out to be exactly the issue.  My "platform" library jar included a persistence.xml file that turns on show_sql, and isn't overridden at run time or Spring wire-up time.

Comment: Also look for `@DataJpaTest(showSql = true)` annotation on a "main"  class. That's something out of Spring Boot though: [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html)

Answer (score 9):

```
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

this will also work

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Hibernate will also log SQL statements if logging for `org.hibernate.SQL` happens at `DEBUG` or `ALL` level, so you could try disabling that (for example with `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=info` when using Log4J).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I already have org.hibernate.SQL logging set to ERROR in log4j. :(

Answer (score 3):

If you are using spring make sure that you don't have the showSql property set to true

I was doing this myself

```
<bean id="vendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate = WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

Comment: Correction: Add the following to your application.properties: `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=OFF`

Comment: If you have a correction, make that edit to your post, don't just throw it in as a comment.

Comment: Your answer does not work for me in the brand new era of Spring in 2020.  I added this and it worked.  "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false"

Answer (score 0):

Here are three ways (they are probably others) to show or hide hibernate sql queries :

1. In logger config (level DEBUG for logback) :

   ```
   <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" />
   ```
2. In Spring config (for instance in java config) :

   ```
   @Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
   final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
   //...
   final Properties jpaProperties = new Properties(); // java.util
   //TODO replace "true" by a variable
   jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true"); 
   lef.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
   return lef;
   }
   ```
3. In persistence.xml

   ```
   <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
   ```

It seems that the logger configuration is independant from the persistence configuration. As for the persistence configuration it appears that spring overrides the persistence.xml (I tested it with a persistence.xml loaded by spring, if this is not the case I don't know what will be the behavior).

A difference between the two configurations is the result logging, with logback it will look like this :

```
2016-08-25 16:05:39,436 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL(92) - alter table ...
```

With the persistence configuration :

```
Hibernate: alter table ...
```

Comment: Actually the question was about how to **stop** SQL logging.