# Can't stop Hibernate from writing log to console (log4j.properties is ok)

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I've already set

```
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
```

and I have disabled all messages in log4j.properties

But Hibernate write to console with all queries & statements.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've set log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO and <property name="show_sql">false</property>, but I still get the hibernate SQL added to my log file. I've searched everything in my project for "show_sql" and "log4j" to find any other references, but there aren't any.  Is there another way to turn on hibernate logging?

Comment: Sorry for the noise, but I was wrong -- doing the things I mentioned DO remove all SQL logging. I discovered that a 3rd-party library I am using has this line hard coded in it:  System.out.println(hql);  Yikes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't make hibernate stop showing SQL using Spring JPA Vendor Adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679518/cant-make-hibernate-stop-showing-sql-using-spring-jpa-vendor-adapter)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Setting the `hibernate.show_sql` to `true` tells hibernate to *Write all SQL statements to console. This is an alternative to setting the log category `org.hibernate.SQL` to debug.*

So even if you set this property to `false`, make sure that you don't have the following category defined (or configured to use a console appender):

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

Also, make sure that you don't set the `hibernate.show_sql` programmatically to true when instancing your `Configuration` object. Hunt something like this:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure().
    .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
```

Note that the `setProperty(String propertyName, String value)` takes as first parameter the full name of a configuration property i.e. `hibernate.show_sql`, not just `show_sql`.

Comment: @Pascal: see my comment to the question. Everything you've suggested, I've looked into. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I use logback (plus slf4j) and I added to my logback config file: `<logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="ALL" />
 <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="WARN" />
 <logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG" />`

Answer (score 2):

HI there, i figured out you can solve this also with this 2 lines in your log4j.properties file.

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate = WARN
log4j.logger.org.hibernate = ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

You adding something like this to log4j.properties?

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate = WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems very strange, but when Use Eclipse with JUnit Test task, all output still goes to Console (in Eclipse Console window).

But when I use ant command for unit testing, nothing goes to console.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you need first to set `hibernate.show_sql` to `false`. This will prevent hibernate output to console or Tomcat stdout log.

But in order to direct your sql output to another log use this code in log4j.xml file:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="hibernate"/>
</logger>
```

To keep the normal hibernate log level (WARN / ERROR) to console use this code in log4j.xml file:

```
<category name="org.hibernate">
    <priority value="WARN" />
</category>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple Just Add dependency to your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.17</version>
```

And it will disable logging and add put in src/main/resources/log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF
```

Then you can use it anytime if you want to display log on console then On it or else OFF