# Stop Hibernate console output, without log4j

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j, slf4j

As said in the title i want to stop Hibernate console output, without using log4j. I have tried to use log4j but i havent got anywhere. 
What i want is the console INFO outputs to stop.
And if i am using log4j is it possible to do it without .properties or .xml files, just set the settings in the source.
tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution looks like adding slf4j-log4j12-1.5.2.jar in your classpath if you are using slf4j-api. This is other than configuration added for log4j for disabling logs.

This link should be useful.

http://ayushsuman.blogspot.com/2010/07/turning-off-hibernate-logging-console.html

You can also check other solutions from :

[Can't stop Hibernate from writing log to console (log4j.properties is ok)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077377/cant-stop-hibernate-from-writing-log-to-console-log4j-properties-is-ok)

Comment: thx, this helps a lot, but this example generates multiple binding warnings of the loggers, but i am getting close to a solution. Tnx ull get a check >D

Comment: so, the first link is not a solution, it just creates not configured ground. So, if u re using log4j  binding, dont use slf4.simple.
The solution is getting all the right versions.
my solution was.
Hibernate 3.5
slf4j-api-1.6.1
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1
log4j-1.2.16

and setting the properties with the PropertyConfigurator from log4j, to FATAL

Comment: @Martes I'm sorry but the blog post mentioned here is plain wrong (I left a comment to explain the problem but the author decided to ignore his mistake and deleted my comment). The author solved his problem "by accident" by putting several bindings on the classpath, hiding the `slf4j-simple` binding. But this is wrong and SLF4J will indeed complain about that. So no offense but this reference is just horribly wrong and this accepted answer is also incorrect. The solution is not to add random SLF4J bindings, the solution is to replace the `slf4j-simple` binding.

Comment: This is not an answer. I came here with the same problem and got no where with this response.

Comment: @ThreaT This is an answer. It may not be a **good answer**, but it is an answer. If you don't think this is a good answer, please downvote it. That's what downvotes are for.

Comment: @DavidWasser: I did downvote it long before your comment. This is not an answer, it would be helpful as a comment but by definition an answer must resolve a question otherwise it's either incorrect or irrelevant (for another question perhaps).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate");
        log.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

It should work. Just call it before you open any sessions.

Comment: He nice, this part helped me a lot to.. tnx .
Well i used it to change the level in the source with out depending on the properites files.

Answer (score 3):

I can certify that Hibernate won't log on the console unless your configuration somehow allows it to do so. So, what version of Hibernate are you using? What SLF4J binding are you using if you're not using LOG4J as logging backend? Do you have a configuration file for it?

Or maybe did you turn on the echoing of SQL to stdout in your `hibernate.cfg.xml`?:

```
<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

You need to help readers a bit, we don't all have crystal balls :) Please provide more material.

---

**Update:** It appears that the OP had the `slf4-simple` [binding](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#binding) on his class path which is precisely used to output `INFO` log messages to the console:

> Binding for [`Simple`](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html) implementation, which outputs all events to `System.err`. Only messages of level INFO and higher are printed. This binding may be useful in the context of small applications.

**Replacing** `slf4-simple` with another binding ([you should not have multiple bindings on the class path](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings)) with the appropriate configuration should silence Hibernate.

Comment: already solver, my comment explains it all. It was my dummy mestake, hibernate does not output if not sad u re right, and the problem was in my bindings, multiple bindings not a good idea, slf4-simple and log4j. but all is solved now. my upper comment shows my solution.

And ill remember to give more info in future. Tnx