# Specify only some packages to have debug output

Tags: java, log4j

I want to log some behavior of my web application which also implements hibernate, spring and so on.  When I tried to implement log4j logger from apache I had some troubles.

When I turn on logger it is also debugging hibernate and spring which I don't want. I tried to configure properties file to the specify the package of my project but it does not work.

Here is my code of property file:

```
log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, O
log4j.category.com.my.package= DEBUG, FILE, O
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log/logger.log
log4j.appender.O=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
.... and some layout
```

It works when I switch `rootCategory = DEBUG` but it is also debugging the hibernate and spring as I said.

Comment: This may help with hibernate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077377/cant-stop-hibernate-from-writing-log-to-console-log4j-properties-is-ok

Comment: How do you create your `Logger` objects?

Comment: @kmb385 your link helps me a lot. thanks

Comment: @kevin initiated properties and call static method getLogger("some_name"); but i already solved it :] but thanks anyway

Comment: When you say `some_name`, would that be like `com.my.package.some_name` or more like `calculator_logs`?  Log4J `Logger`s form a hierarchy based on the periods in their names, so it is usually best to name your loggers with the same names as the classes that are doing the logging.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you have to specfiy the log level per package:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
log4j.logger.org.springframework=info
log4j.logger.com.yourapplication=debug
```

Note that you should switch from categories (obsolete) to loggers. So `log4j.rootLogger=...`

Comment: Why would you not just specify `ERROR` for the root logger and then `DEBUG` for the specific package that needs debugging?

Comment: @Kevin i don't know why but it just don't work that way for me.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to know the name of the loggers that are actually writing stuff... The simplest way is to set the root category to error:

```
log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, 0
```

Then set the level for your logs accordingly:

```
log4j.com.your.package=DEBUG...
```

Setting the `rootCategory` to `DEBUG` will turn *everything* to `DEBUG`, unless you specifically configure a logger otherwise.

B.T.W, this is NOT a hibernate issue, this is related to how you are configuring your logger.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, but I think because the question asker is not naming the logger objects like `com.your.package.foo.bar`, the DEBUG configuration line has no effect.