# log4j - Configuration, Ignoring the lib/jar Logging

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am working on a java application and I am using log4j for logging. My **"log4j.properties"** file (in WEB-INF/conf) is here -

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n 

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.R.File=C:/billingAutomationService/infotrac20.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=30MB 
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10 
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

In my application there are a some debug messages with `logger.debug("debug message")`. But with the configuration I ca not see these debug message in my log file - **"stdout.log"**. To see the debug message in my log file (**"stdout.log"**) I have added the following line in my `log4j.properties` file -

```
 log4j.rootLogger=debug,stdout
```

But adding this line enables all **'DEBUG'** level on my jar/lib along the whole project. I am using a log of `spring`, `hibernate` and other jars/libs. This incident makes my log file (**"stdout.log"**) very large even on a single operation. Because a lots of **'DEBUG'** message coming from the standard lib/jars which I don't want to debug. Is there any way to turn off the debug message coming form the lib/jars?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below thread.

[log4j: package-specific logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297686/log4j-package-specific-logging)

Usually you would have a common package starting for all your files, only enable debug for those package names.

Use root logger as warn.

Also.

[Specify only some packages to have debug output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796411/specify-only-some-packages-to-have-debug-output)