# JPA monitor for persistence context

Tags: java, jpa, monitor

How convinion debug state of persistence context, watch result of queries, monitor all entities?

Is some JPA monitor for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362876/how-to-view-the-sql-queries-issues-by-jpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using EclipseLink, there is a performance monitor option,

see,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Performance_Monitoring_and_Profiling/Performance_Monitoring

You can also configure logging,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging