# JPA: how do you get/print the JPQL query string behind a (typed) query after parameters have been set?

Tags: java, debugging, jpa, jpql

How do you get/print the JPQL query string behind a (typed) query, that is **after** parameters have been set? (e.g. for debugging purposes)

A simple `toString()` doesn't seem to do the trick...

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362876/how-to-view-the-sql-queries-issued-by-jpa

Comment: I had expected this... I was **not** asking about displaying the provider-generated SQL.

Comment: why not define what you mean in terms of the the output? Having a parameter set is irrelevant to the JPQL "string" form ... a parameter is ":myParam" in the JPQL string form.

Comment: I would like the final JPQL that ultimately gets translated to the final SQL, that is including the concrete arguments been set/used. Looks like you have to compile that string yourself with String.replace...?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the final JPQL that ultimately gets translated to the final SQL". How a JPA implementation generates the SQL is down to it, and parameters in general will never be substituted into any String. SQL is generated from expression trees etc not a String. If you want param values inserting in then do it yourself since it only makes sense to you

Comment: Why don't you put that as an answer?

Comment: In any case, no matter how JPA providers handle their stuff internally, it would definitely be of interest to sometimes see what the final query would look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as "the final JPQL that ultimately gets translated to the final SQL". How a JPA implementation generates the SQL is down to it, and parameters in general will never be substituted into any String. SQL is generated from expression trees etc not a String. If you want param values inserting in then do it yourself since it only makes sense to you

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but the current answer doesn't exactly answer the original/root question.

I believe Kawu was looking for what the JPQL string looked like, not if it gets converted to SQL or not. The desire was the find the concrete parameter.

Anyway Kawu, I was looking for the same thing at one time because my query results were skewed and I couldn't tell what the parameter was. I found that adding the below code to the persistence.xml did the trick. I use EclipseLink, but I am sure other JPA implementaitons have something like this:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
```

This shows the below in your server logs:

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2016-10-24 16:02:08.577--ServerSession(13483501)--Connection(6214343)--Thread(Thread[27010968@qtp-10395070-0,5,main])--SELECT ID, Name FROM Test WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [<your parameter shows here>]
```

Answer (score 0):

For JBoss users: make the change in standalone.xml.  In that file you will find a logging section under <profile>, eg:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
```

Default level is INFO.  To get queries etc. to be shown, change the level to DEBUG in two places, as in:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
```

Re-start JBoss and now your console is filled with chatter.