# hibernate logback sql

Tags: spring, hibernate, logback, spring-data

I want to see the actual parameters of my SQL queries when I use Hibernate. I add this to my logback.xml to see the queries (with question marks):

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="TRACE" />
```

but to no effect.

Is there any special configuration necessary?

OnConsoleStatusListener shows me the correct configuration

```
23:48:15,246 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.type] to TRACE
```

but no output from org.hibernate.type package.

I'm using Spring with Jpa.

Comment: Think maybe this help, works for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4367283/2162488
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Things you have to make sure:

1. Are you sure that SLF4J + LogBack is working in your app?
2. Is your logger pointing to any appender?

Comment: Yes to both questions, I'm using ConsoleAppender and I see every other log output (for example spring logging) and some other hibernate logging

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured an appended?

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <!-- "application-name" is a variable -->
    <File>c:/logs/${application-name}.log</File>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>%d %p %t %c - %m%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I'm just using ConsoleAppender at the moment (very initial development phase)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this configuration, and it works for me:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="trace" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
</logger>
```

Comment: If I use `ref="STDOUT"` this also works for me. That is because we have `<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">`[…] already in the configuration, and a `ref` needs to refer to a name, not a `class`.

Answer (score 1):

The logger that works for me is the following:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="TRACE" />
```