# why my mysql query is not working in JPA?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

```
@Query(value = "select * from employee where ? = ?", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(String key, String value);
```

The Structure of Employee is

> Id
>
> Age
>
> Name

when i call getEmployees with("Age",21) im getting List with zero length.
in the console the query is displayed as

> select * from employee where ? = ?

Comment: Are you sure you can have the column name as a parameter as well and not just the value? If it is ok then the next question is if the age value you send will get implicitly converted to the data type of the Age column, String to int?

Comment: I'm not sure about passing the column name as a parameter.

Comment: I am not an expert on JPA but can't you see the actual SQL query (after ? has been replaced with values) in some log?

Comment: select * from employee where ? = ? this is what I got in the log, the passed values didn't replace the '?' placeholder

Comment: Maybe you could put in [an effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362876/how-to-view-the-sql-queries-issued-by-jpa)

Comment: in the SQL layer both are considered as values, I think this wont work like this,  prepared statements in SQL can do the job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JPQL for custom Query

```
public List getEmployees(String key, String value) 
{

    Query query = (Query) entityManager.createQuery("from Employee where " + key + " = " + value);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Autowire  the EntityManager.

Answer (score 0):

Use JPQL, so the query will look something like this.

```js
@Query(value = "select * from employee where :key = :value", nativeQuery = true)
public List < Employee > getEmployees(@Param("key") String key, @Param("value") String value);
```

Comment: Didn't work for me 
Still, it is showing "select * from employee where ? = ?"

Comment: Hibernate uses prepared statements so you can't see the full SQL. You can set the log level for org.hibernate.type to trace to see the values bound to the parameters. So that's the reason you see '?'.
See this link for better understanding [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql/2536835#2536835]

Try not passing the key and manually pass the key:
`@Query(value = "select * from employee where age = :value", nativeQuery = true)
public List < Employee > getEmployees(@Param("key") String key, @Param("value") String value);`

Comment: The key and value will be dynamic, the user may enter **id=1** or **name=john** or  **age=23**  so, "select * from employee where age = :value", nativeQuery = true" this will return employee record based only on age.