# Getting the JPQL/SQL String Representations for a Criteria Query

Tags: java, eclipselink, jpql

How to Getting the SQL String Representations for a Criteria Query with parmetervalue ?

I tried this but it returns a string to me without the parameter values:

```
String QueryString = 'SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE lastname = ?'


query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(QueryString);

query.setParameter(1, "toto");

System.out.print(query.unwrap(JpaQuery.class).getDatabaseQuery().getSQLString());
```

But returns "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE lastname = ?"
instead of "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE lastname = 'toto'"

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362876/how-to-view-the-sql-queries-issued-by-jpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @GrootCfor helping me find the solution.

If it helps other people here is the solution:

```
String QueryString = 'SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE lastname = ?';
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(QueryString); 
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class).getActiveSession();  
DatabaseQuery databaseQuery = query.unwrap(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.JpaQuery.class).getDatabaseQuery();
DatabaseRecord recordWithValues= new DatabaseRecord();

query.setParameter(1, "toto"); 
recordWithValues.add(new DatabaseField(Integer.toString(1)), "toto");

databaseQuery.prepareCall(session, recordWithValues); 
String sqlStringWithArgs = databaseQuery.getTranslatedSQLString(session, recordWithValues);

System.out.print(sqlStringWithArgs);

====SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE lastname = 'toto'====
```