# Will calling merge method on a managed entity without changes update underlying database?

Tags: jpa, merge, derby

```
// pm is a product manager object which handles actual database calls
Product product = pm.findProduct( 1 );
List<Product> products = pm.findAllProducts();
products.stream().forEach( System.out::println );

pm.update( product ); // pm object delegates by calling merge on an entity manager object
products = pm.findAllProducts();
products.stream().forEach( System.out::println );
```

Both `println` statements print same number of records, without any change. As there is no state change in `product` managed entity,

1. Will persistence provider(PP) still send it to the database for update? State for both cases: when second-level cache is and is not used.
2. If no, how does PP determine changes?
3. If yes, as there's no difference in second output, how do I know for sure that database updated the record? IOW, how can I determine that database had executed an update statement?

EDIT: Added 'derby' tag.

Answer (score 1):

"how can I determine that database had executed an update statement?"
You can enable sql logging and look in log which sql queries are executed.
    [How to view the SQL queries issued by JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362876/how-to-view-the-sql-queries-issued-by-jpa)

Comment: I'm interested to know similar thing at 'database' side.

Answer (score 0):

1. As per logging, persistence provider does not issue an update statement.
2. This could be JPA implementation specific.