# Java EntityManager transaction gets broken, how to locate the SQL that causes it?

Tags: java, transactions, entitymanager

I have an EntityManager and a JobDAO class which has many methods which use the EntityManager to select/update/delete/insert.

For some methods, I now am getting a `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException`: `Executing an update/delete query ..`
about not having a transaction.

I have a `@Transactional` annotation on the method calling the other methods.

I have now fixed it somewhat by using my own database connection for some of these commands, but I'd like to find the SQL that causes the problem.

One idea I have is to add a transaction checker method call to the end of each of the 20 methods that are suspicious. But I'd like to know whether you have a better idea to check on the EntityManager, for example by logging all SQL so I can find the last SQL where it stopped working.

Comment: There is a configuration property for the EntityManagerFactory that will cause your ORM provider (Hibernate?) to log all sql. See: https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362876/how-to-view-the-sql-queries-issued-by-jpa) on SO for configuring the ORM provider (e.g. Hibernate, etc.) to **log sql**:
[How to view the SQL queries issued by JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362876/how-to-view-the-sql-queries-issued-by-jpa)

In addition, you can programatically ask the EntityManager if it is currently in a transaction, see [isJoinedToTransaction()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#isJoinedToTransaction--).

Also..., make sure that the class with the methods that have the @Transactional annotation is a Spring Bean, otherwise the annotation does nothing.

In addition you have to tell Spring to enable transaction management. This post will help you understand how to do that: https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring

Comment: I don't have an `application.properties` file. Where would I place it?

Comment: This post on Baeldung will help you understand how to configure your jpa provider: https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa