# Debugging createNativeQuery calls in Java based app

Tags: java

We have a system built in Java and we can create custom javascript "macros" in it. It uses Java entities but I have zero exposure to Java. I'm trying to debug the following because the sql doesn't seem to work. In PHP I would use something like var_dump to see what the sql statement actually looks like.

Is there a way to see what " getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sqlStr)" is actually sending?

```
function insertTempHeaderRecord(filereadid, lineArray){
    try{
        var sqlStr="INSERT INTO vl_edisalesorder (filereadid, edifilename, customerid, deladdressid, contactid, "
        "pricelistid, customerref, orderdate, delivercontact, delivertelephone, taillift, bookdelivery, deliveryins, orderid "+
        " VALUES (:param0, :param1, :param2, :param3, :param4, :param5, :param6, :param7, :param8, :param9, :param10, :param11, :param12, :param13) ";
        getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sqlStr)
            .setParameter("param0", filereadid)         
            .setParameter("param1", filereadid)
            .setParameter("param2", trimTo(lineArray[3],10))  //traderid
            .setParameter("param3", trimTo(lineArray[4], 10))  //deladd
            .setParameter("param4", trimTo(lineArray[5],10))   //contactid
            .setParameter("param5", "0536")
            .setParameter("param6", trimTo(lineArray[2],25))   //custref
            .setParameter("param7", Packages.java.sql.Date(orderdate.getTime()))
            .setParameter("param8", trimTo(lineArray[8],25))  //delcontact
            .setParameter("param9", trimTo(lineArray[6],20)) //deltel  
            .setParameter("param10", importer.Boolean.valueOf(lineArray[9]))  //tlrq
            .setParameter("param11", importer.Boolean.valueOf(lineArray[10])) //delbook
            .setParameter("param12", trimTo(lineArray[7],30))    //delinstr 
            .setParameter("param13", importer.Boolean.valueOf(lineArray[10]))   //delivery book in
            .executeUpdate();
    }catch(err){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
logger.info("Petestestworkflow.xml - this worked ok");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to view the SQL queries issued by JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362876/how-to-view-the-sql-queries-issued-by-jpa)

Comment: Sadly not. This is in a bespoke environment, not Java.

Comment: Then I would suggest to add more details here in your question.