# Is there any JPQL analyzer?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql, analyzer

I developed app using `JPA Toplink` which uses JPQL. According to my research JPA will call more SQL than what JPQL statement look like.

I'm looking for some JPQL analyzer tools like I can execute JPQL or run my application and
tells me how many actual SQL being run.

Is there anything like that available?

**UPDATE**
Added the following in my persistence.xml as suggested and my Netbean IDE now shows actual SQL generated by JPQL :D

```
  <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="JavaLogger"/>
      <property name="toplink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there can be a generic analyzer as the behavior is provider specific. You can however look at the SQL's being executed by enabling appropriate logs of the JPA provider you are using.

Hibernate:

[Can't make hibernate stop showing SQL using Spring JPA Vendor Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679518/cant-make-hibernate-stop-showing-sql-using-spring-jpa-vendor-adapter)

EclipseLink:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/glassfish_and_jpa_sql_monitoring

OpenJPA:

http://openjpa.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowdoIseetheSQLthatOpenJPAisexecuting%253F

Comment: Thanks for the link! wondering there is one for Toplink (sorry I didn't specify in first place.. edited)

Comment: EclipseLink is TopLink. So follow the EclipeLink links or here is another one http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/07/06/toplink-essentials-enhancements-category-specific-logging-level-and-cascade-refresh-